# Snippet to generate MULTIPLE methods

Tags: c#

I have classes that are fluent and follow the builder pattern. For example a typical class might look like this:

```
public class ItemBuilder
{
   private string _id = "SMITH-1001001";


   //code for implementing the builder omitted for brevity

   public ItemBuilder WithId(string id)
   {
      this._id = id;
      return this;
   }

}
```

Now it is not uncommon to be implementing a builder object for some poco that has multiple private fields (the one I'm staring at has 66) and I need to have a method as seen above for modifying each one if altering from the default.

I know how to create a snippet to generate a single method and tab through changing values as appropriate. I can also highlight a chunk of code and chose the snippet to wrap with try block.

So what I am wondering is if there is a way to mass generate the methods since they are 100% predictable.

For example I could highlight all 66 fields and choose my snippet which would generate 66 methods.

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer is....you can't do this via snippets. However the objective can still be met. What I ended up doing was writing a regular expression that parsed out the values then inserted them into a string. So I would copy all the private fields I wanted to use from vs to notepad ++. I then did a ctrl-h and put the regex in the find and the replacement string in the replace. From there it generated my methods and I cut and paste back to vs. Not 100% smooth but far better than manually typing them all.

Comment: You are right, you can't do this via snippets. You may want to try using TTTT (shortened T4), a code generation feature in Visual Studio. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx